# When does Java Web Start hide the splash screen and is it possible to control it?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, java-web-start, jnlp

With java web start one can define a splash screen in the JNLP, is it possible to control when to hide this splash screen from the application code?

On the method "public static void main(String[] args)" on the class indicated as "mainClass" of the "main" jnlp jar. When i do "SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()" it returns "null" as it seems that it gets disposed even before the hitting "public static void main(String[] args)" or that java web start uses a different splash screen mechanism (not java.awt.SplashScreen)?

I am just trying to implement a smooth startup process from the java web start splash screen to the application

Comment: *"When does Java Web Start hide the splash screen"* Not documented, so - whenever it feels like it, really *"..and is it possible to control it?"* Nope. We might have some control over the `SplashScreen` class in AWT, but JWS does not use that.

Comment: What I do know is that there are two java processess when I launch. The first one that shows the splash screen in the jnlp will run a DownloadServiceListener. That JVM dies just before firing the one that actually runs the app. In this case, this second JVM doesn't have a SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() for sure. Just trying to implement a smooth start transition